# How do I add posts to my page through the Facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying to figure out the Facebook api for hours now and with all the markers, I get an answer: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '***' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

I've already created about 5 different tokens on different pages, and I'm trying to execute code like this:

```py
from facebook_business.adobjects.page import Page
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi

access_token = '***'
id = '***'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token, proxies=proxies)

fields = []
params = {}
print(Page(id).get_feed(fields=fields, params=params))
```

But all the time I get the same answer.

Does anyone know how to work with this? I have a page and I just want to add news to it through the api.

- Created both types of applications
- Generated the token through both the marketing api and the explorer
- I read the old answers, but as I understand, the api policy changes frequently and I did not find anything useful

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing#publish-a-page-post says which permissions should suffice.

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry, but my ass is already on fire. Why does Facebook have such a "good" api? Why did they make a bunch of incomprehensible functionality that you have to open a few dozen pages in the documentation to figure out? I created a user token and a page token with the permissions pages_manage_posts and pages_read_engagement via Graph API Explorer, but still nothing works with any token. My code:
```
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token='*')
print(Page('*').create_feed(fields=[], params={'message': '***'}))
```
Response:
(#100) The global id *** is not allowed for this call

Comment: Try and get the request working _in_ Graph API Explorer first. Once you got that working, all the permissions correct etc., you can try and implement it via your own code.

Comment: As CBoe said, first try adding the post through Graph API Explorer. May be try with this simple request:-`curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed?message=Hello Fans!&access_token={page-access-token}"` This way you can be make sure if you have added all the required permissions.

Comment: Do you have the privilege to add posts directly to Facebook with its UI?

Comment: @CBroe
Trying to follow these instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/

"Get a Long-lived User Access Token" - No problem getting a long-lived token
"Get a Page Access Token" - I use this long-lived token and I get a response back: 
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '***' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read ...",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "***"
  }
}

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a wrong ID? Input your token under https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/, and check what page ID that actually shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back after a few days. What did I get with this interesting experience? Facebook made it a little confusing.

The ID parameter in the url address DOES NOT equal the page or profile ID

In the Graph API Explorer, in the "Access token" field, you must always enter the right token, even if the same token needs to be entered in the url, which means you simply duplicate the token in the url and in the field.

On the one hand understandable, but on the other hand a bit confusing documentation, where probably everyone may have questions like "And how do I do that?"

All in all, I managed to do it successfully once and I don't want to repeat this experience any time soon. Records can publish through the api and this is the main thing. Thank you all.